# Интересует самый простой и действенный способ защиты от спам запросов по GET

Tags: php, form, сессия, форма, спам

Интересует самый простой и действенный способ защиты от спам запросов по GET. Есть форма которая методом GET отправляет запрос в файл <handler.php> с параметром id. Метод капчи эффективен, но не удобен для пользователя. Я рассматриваю на данный момент способ с сессиями - на стороне формы формируется некое значение и сохраняется в сессию, а далее оно же проверяется уже на стороне файла <handler.php>.

Comment: Первый и главный вопрос зачем это делать? Чего вы хотите добиться? Даже если вы поставите капчу или какой-то csrf токен, либо сессии я всё равно смогу отправлять запросы на открытый порт и они дойдут в любом случае. Единственный способ защититься от запросов - закрыть порт, но тогда никто не сможет отправлять запросы. Во всех остальных случаях запросы будут доставлены в любом случае)

Comment: я понимаю вы смотрите очень глубоко, на этом уровне справится антифлуд демон сервера, а вот со стороны массы народа это должно сократить трафик ошибочный или школьный )

Comment: сохраняете в localStorage на стороне клиента время последнего запроса, Перед запросом проверяете время отправки последнего запроса

Comment: @Inventor и как проверить это время перед запросом?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов перед запросом достать из localStorage предыдущее время отправки и сравнить с текущим временем. Например если прошло меньше 10 минут отклонить запрос (или любое другое время)

Comment: слишком жестко - допустим ждать будет 15 минут или 15,5 мин) здесь не угадаешь

Comment: @Inventor Ну, это же проверка уже на сервере. То есть запрос уже отправлен, и вы просто обрабатываете его по-другому. По сути, это то, что и в самом вопросе предложено: сессия и пр...

Comment: Да запрос отправлен, но при этом он не обрабатывается, вот в чем дело, на стороне сервера запрашиваются данные по id. Вопрос в ценности обращения, при получении запроса файл делает запрос к БД. С другой стороны можно данные добавлять без проверки, и только в конце процедуры сравнивать данные на соответствие с БД?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов это как раз проверка на стороне клиента, документация по localStorage: https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Comment: @Inventor да, и правда, туплю. А правда, можно ли это рассматривать как метод защиты от спама? ведь значение можно поменять на клиенте при желании.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов я уже говорил выше, что на стороне клиента невозможно вообще ни от чего защититься, потому что это всё можно изменить, такая защита называется "от дурака". А от спама вообще никак невозможно защититься даже на стороне сервера

Comment: да логичнее тогда добавят данные без проверки в реальном времени (доверяя уже сформированному массиву) через простой JS, а уже в процессе финальной стадии пробежать весь список и проверить их на cсоответствие с БД и вот тут то и впихнуть капчу.